# Logging all packets in firewalld

Tags: logging, firewalld

We're trying to configure firewalld to log all incoming packets. So far I've only managed to log only rejected packets with `LogDenied=off` that shows:

```
 FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:dd:3a:26:18:2d:dd:34:5f:78:9a:bc:ff:00 SRC=65.13.35.231 DST=10.0.1.5 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=102 ID=31984 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49886 DPT=3385 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

But I need to log accepted packets as well. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: Did you consider traffic size to be logged? If not done carefully or for a limited time duration, this will cause you performance troubles.

Comment: Yes, the calls made to this specific system will be limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tag any rule with a prefix to identify accepted rules:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=10.20.0.0/16 port port=1234 protocol=tcp log prefix="MyTagHere " level=info accept'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We ended up going with Opnsense, but this should be relevant for others. :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported on firewalld yet. Took the devs long enough to implement a command to log denied packets....

Comment: and what about now ?